# Selecting Persons in table and exclude wife but combine their names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Person`:

```
PersonID | FirstName | LastName
-------------------------------
1        |   John    |  Doe
2        |   Jane    |  Doe
3        |  NoSpouse | Morales
4        | Jonathan  | Brand
5        | Shiela    | Wife
```

And a `Relationship` table:

```
RelationshipID | PersonID | Type | RelatedPersonID
1              |    1     |  3   |     2
2              |    2     |  3   |     1
3              |    4     |  3   |     5
4              |    5     |  3   |     4
```

So basically, I want to combine the names of the spouse and client, but I want to exclude the spouse:

**Expected Results:**

```
1,  John and Jane Doe, 2
----------------------
3, NoSpouse Morales, null
-----------------------
4, Jonathan and Shiela Brand, 5
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT p.PersonID,
    Case when spouse.PersonID is not null 
        THEN p.FirstName + ' and ' + spouse.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
    ELSE p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName END as ClientName,
    spouse.PersonID as RelatedPersonID
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Relationship r on p.PersonID = r.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Person spouse on r.RelatedPersonID = spouse.PersonID
WHERE r.Type = 3 OR spouse.PersonID is null
```

but the results are:

```
1,  John and Jane Doe, 2
----------------------
2,  Jane and John Doe, 1
----------------------
3, NoSpouse Morales, null
-----------------------
4, Jonathan and Shiela Brand, 5
-------------------------------
5, Shiela and Jonathan Wife, 4
```

Here's some mock data:

```
create table Person(
    PersonID int primary key,
    FirstName varchar(max),
    LastName varchar(max)
)
insert into Person values 
(1, 'John', 'Doe'), 
(2, 'Jane', 'Doe'), 
(3, 'NoSpouse', 'Morales'), 
(4, 'Jonathan', 'Brand'), 
(5,'Shiela','Wife')

create table Relationship (
    RelationshipID int,
    PersonID int references Person(PersonID),
    Type int,
    RelatedPersonID int references Person(PersonID)
)
insert into Relationship values 
(1, 1, 3, 2),
(2, 2, 3, 1),
(3, 4, 3, 5),
(4, 5, 3, 4)

SELECT p.PersonID,
    Case when spouse.PersonID is not null 
        THEN p.FirstName + ' and ' + spouse.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
    ELSE p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName END as ClientName,
    spouse.PersonID as RelatedPersonID
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Relationship r on p.PersonID = r.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Person spouse on r.RelatedPersonID = spouse.PersonID
WHERE r.Type = 3 OR spouse.PersonID is null

drop table Relationship
drop table Person
```

thanks in advance for your help and time.

**NOTE:**
I've edited my mock script to include `3, NoSpouse Morales, null` in the results. Also, there is no particular criteria needed to which is husband/wife. Whoever was fetched first in the list should not include the related spouse.

Comment: If you look at your data what is the criteria to detect who is the husband and who is the wife? I don't see any criteria. Without a criteria you cannot write a query.

Comment: gender is not really important. if the first person is already in the results, the spouse should not be included

Comment: Werner means, how would you choose between 'Jane and Joe Doe' and 'Joe and Jane Doe'?

Comment: So a result including "2,  Jane and John Doe, 1" but not "1,  John and Jane Doe, 2" is also OK?

Comment: On a purely non-programming note, I would be wary of renaming Shiela Wife without her express permission. Consider dropping the second surname only if it matches the first.

Comment: You don't have any logic to handle last names. If "Lou Segusi" is spousal with respect to "Carmine Dioxide", but neither chooses to change their last name, what result do you want? Pick one? Pick both? Surgical hyphenation? Anullment?

Comment: Polygamy is gonna be fun to deal with...

Comment: If they're married, or otherwise a couple, I think choosing any of their last names would be acceptable to both parties. It's just a representation anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If one has to be included while the other excluded, try adding a clause

```
AND r.PersonID < r.RelatedPersonID
```

since the IDs will not be equal and this will include only either one:

```
 SELECT p.PersonID,
 Case when spouse.PersonID is not null 
    THEN p.FirstName + ' and ' + spouse.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
 ELSE p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName END as ClientName,
 spouse.PersonID as RelatedPersonID
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Relationship r on p.PersonID = r.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Person spouse on r.RelatedPersonID = spouse.PersonID
WHERE (r.Type = 3 AND r.PersonID < r.RelatedPersonID)  OR spouse.PersonID is null
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work

```
SELECT p.PersonID,
    Case when spouse.PersonID is not null 
        THEN p.FirstName + ' and ' + spouse.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
    ELSE p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName END as ClientName,
    spouse.PersonID as RelatedPersonID
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Relationship r on p.PersonID = r.PersonID and r.Type = 3
LEFT JOIN Person spouse on r.RelatedPersonID = spouse.PersonID
WHERE  coalesce(r.PersonID, 1) < coalesce(r.RelatedPersonID, 2)
```

This way you only take into account relationship rows where `PersonID` is lower than `RelatedPersonID`, or rows that don't join with `Relationships` table at all (because `1 < 2` is always true)

Comment: yep.. this seems the same with @dev8080's answer. Up for the explanation though.

Comment: Yes it's basically the same... he beat me by 45 seconds :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just remove the spouses in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT PersonId, ClientName, RelatedPersonID
FROM (SELECT p.PersonID,
             (CASE WHEN spouse.PersonID is not null 
                   THEN p.FirstName + ' and ' + spouse.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
                   ELSE p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
              END) as ClientName,
             spouse.PersonID as RelatedPersonID,
             spouse.LastName as spouse_lastname
      FROM Person p LEFT JOIN
           Relationship r 
           ON p.PersonID = r.PersonID LEFT JOIN
           Person spouse 
           ON r.RelatedPersonID = spouse.PersonID
      WHERE r.Type = 3 
     ) prs
WHERE spouse_LastName <> 'Wife';
```

Comment: this means that i have to manually supply the spouse last names, right

Comment: I think 'Wife' was just an example name.

Comment: @GeomanYabes . . . The example data has "wife" as the last name.  It is only possible to answer the question that is asked.

Comment: but i also included the expected result. ^^, thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table Person(
   PersonID int primary key,
   FirstName varchar(max),
   LastName varchar(max)
)
insert into Person values 
(1, 'John', 'Doe'), 
(2, 'Jane', 'Doe'), 
(3, 'NoSpouse', 'Morales'), 
(4, 'Jonathan', 'Brand'), 
(5,'Shiela','Wife')

create table Relationship (
   RelationshipID int,
   PersonID int references Person(PersonID),
   Type int,
   RelatedPersonID int references Person(PersonID)
)
insert into Relationship values 
(1, 1, 3, 2),
(2, 2, 3, 1),
(3, 4, 3, 5),
(4, 5, 3, 4)

SELECT p.PersonID,
   Case when spouse.PersonID is not null 
      THEN p.FirstName + ' and ' + spouse.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
   ELSE p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName END as ClientName,
   spouse.PersonID as RelatedPersonID
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Relationship r on p.PersonID = r.PersonID AND r.Type = 3 
LEFT JOIN Person spouse on r.RelatedPersonID = spouse.PersonID
WHERE r.RelationshipID IS NULL OR  r.RelationshipID < r.RelatedPersonID

drop table Relationship
drop table Person
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/WMEM80911)

Comment: You should add an explanation on what your query does to accomplish the desired results.