# invoice type fetch query from tables

Tags: mysql

[ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tPVE.png)

ER diagram is attached

I need to get sales invoice invoices.type = 'sales' and invoices.type = 'purchase'
 with company name as you can see in select statement
also sales and purchase columns

My query

```
SELECT jobs.id as jobID,
         -- c.name AS Customer,jobs.job_no, 
             invoices.invoice_due_date,
             jobs.id, 
                ( (invoice_items.amount * invoice_items.quantity * invoice_items.exchange_rate )) as Ammount
FROM invoices
INNER JOIN `invoice_items` ON invoices.id = invoice_items.invoice_id 
INNER JOIN `jobs`                ON jobs.id = invoices.job_id


 -- INNER JOIN `company` as c ON  c.company_id  =   jobs.company_id  -- jobs and company.


WHERE invoices.type = 'sales'

--   new conditions
    AND MONTH(jobs.created_at) = '3'
    AND YEAR(jobs.created_at) = '2017' 
    AND jobs.status > 0
    AND jobs.complete_job > 0
    AND jobs.completed_at IS NOT NULL

    AND   invoice_items.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY  jobs.job_no
ORDER BY  invoices.invoice_due_date DESC
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used? (Invalid GROUP BY anyway... The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.)

Comment: "I need to get sales invoice invoices.type = 'sales' and invoices.type = 'purchase'...":  
`WHERE (invoices.type = 'sales' OR invoices.type ='purchase')`

Comment: @jarlh i was using SUM(  (invoice_items.amount * invoice_items.quantity * invoice_items.exchange_rate )) as Ammount )

Comment: Required output

Jobnumber  | Customer(company name) |  Sales | Purchase | GrossProfit
---------------    ----------------------------------     ------      ------------   ---------------

Comment: as @GordonLinoff stated, you should provide sample data and your expected results. something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321150/selecting-persons-in-table-and-exclude-wife-but-combine-their-names

Comment: @Peter, what a sample data. :D I bet this is a backup of your database.

Comment: @GeomanYabes any would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated...

```
SELECT jobs.id as jobID,
    C.name AS Customer,jobs.job_no, 
    invoices.invoice_due_date,
    jobs.id, 
    ( (invoice_items.amount * invoice_items.quantity *invoice_items.exchange_rate )) as Ammount,
    CASE invoices.type 
       WHEN 'sales' THEN 'S' 
    ELSE 'P' 
    END as trans_type 
FROM invoices
INNER JOIN `invoice_items` ON invoices.id = invoice_items.invoice_id 
INNER JOIN `jobs`                ON jobs.id = invoices.job_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `company` as C ON  C.company_id = jobs.company_id
WHERE (invoices.type = 'sales' OR invoices.type = 'purchase') AND (MONTH(jobs.created_at) = '3') AND (YEAR(jobs.created_at) = '2017') AND (jobs.status > 0) AND (jobs.complete_job > 0) AND (jobs.completed_at IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @chigs
Need columns in select too 
columns are like 
Jobnumber | 
Customer(company name) | 
Sales | 
Purchase | 
GrossProfit

Comment: sample data  link to download https://ufile.io/j9cnx
as well as here is the select 
    SELECT jobs.id as jobID,
    --     c.name AS Customer,jobs.job_no, 
        invoices.invoice_due_date,         
        SUM( (invoice_items.amount * invoice_items.quantity * invoice_items.exchange_rate ) ) as Ammount

Comment: how we can differentiate between sales and purchase types in SELECT statement so I can calcute anything in select? any thoughts

Comment: I had updated the answer as you told late... anyways take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I really appreciate that.Customer names are empty with no data

Comment: It's because of the values you inserted in database. for that you can try INNER JON instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN ,but in that records with null values of company will be skipped.

Comment: changed to inner join and it is showing the names now only ammount is incorrect see http://prntscr.com/ez42tf  
Job id 1015
Expected sales invoice ammount Total: PKR 63,028.00
Correct ammount :  http://prntscr.com/ez437y

and currently it is showing 859852.0000 ammount for job id 1015

Comment: Bro, I just told as per you question, calculations depends on you.I think all your queries has been solved now. so check your calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.